# intent with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP not clearing the top activity

Tags: android

**Scenario :**

1. I navigate from activity A -> B.
2. I pull down notification drawer and click on the notification which has an intent to start Activity A.

**What i want :**

3. Activity B closes and it's parent A is shown.
4. I click back button to exit the app.

**What actually happens :**

A new instance of Activity A is shown.
If i click back, A closes and the old B shows up.
I have to click back again to go to #3 and #4

I used the intent flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP in the notification's action intent. I also tried FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK in conjunction. I have set both the activities to SingleTop launchMode as well.

What am i doing wrong? Why isn't B(the top) getting cleared even though i use the flag.

Manifest with activities A and B :

```
<activity
        android:name=".A"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<activity
    android:name=".B"
    android:parentActivityName=".A" 
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".A" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Service to show notification :

```
Intent contentIntent = new Intent(this,A.class);
contentIntent.setAction(MYACTION);
contentIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
PendingIntent contentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notificationId, contentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyApplication.getContext())
    .setContentTitle("text")
    .setContentText("text")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setContentIntent(contentPendingIntent);    

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) MyApplication.getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(notificationId,notificationBuilder.build());
```

[EDIT 15-Oct-2014] : It works now as expected without making any changes at all. Even if i remove the flags and the singletop launchmode, it still works. I have no idea why. This is just weird.

Comment: It will be better if you put your code

Comment: @NadirB done. pls have a look now.

Answer (score 0):

in your A Activity add this snippet

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 super.onBackPressed();
}
```

if it dosen't work for you I'll give another solution

Comment: I was hoping to resolve it using the intent flags instead i.e. i am looking for the exact behaviour that `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` is designed for. I can't understand why it won't work as specified by the docs.

Answer (score 0):

try it using set flag as below -

```
Intent contentIntent = new Intent(this,A.class);
contentIntent.setAction(MYACTION);
contentIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
contentIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Comment: This made no difference.